# execCommand('copy') not working programatically, only when executed via DevTools console

Tags: javascript, copy-paste, execcommand, javascript-injection

Source:

```js
const package = document.querySelector('td[data-bind="text: packageName"');
 
if (package.textContent.indexOf('Adaptive') !== -1) {
    package.click();
   
    const stacks_tab = document.querySelector('ul[class="tabsExpanded"]').children[5];
   
    stacks_tab.click();
   
    function get_sources() {
        const sources = [];
 
        const stacks = document.querySelectorAll('span[data-bind="text:duration"]');
 
        for (let i = 0; i < stacks.length; i++) {
            stacks[i].click();
                   
            let renditions = document.querySelectorAll('span[class="blockUnSelected"]');
            renditions[(i+1) * 8 - 1].click();
 
            sources.push(document.querySelectorAll('p[data-bind="text: $data.name"]')[0].textContent);
        }
 
        let copy = '';
 
        for (let i = 0; i < sources.length; i++) {
            const change_brackets = sources[i].replace(/\/tveorigin\/vod\/ae\//, '');
            const no_pd1 = change_brackets.replace(/-pd1/g, '');
            copy += no_pd1 + ',';
        }
       
        if (copy === '') {
            setTimeout(get_sources, 500);
        } else {
            const hidden = document.createElement('input');
            hidden.value = copy;
            document.querySelector('body').appendChild(hidden);
            hidden.select();
           
            function copy_sources() {
                console.log('running');
               
                hidden.select();
               
                if (!document.execCommand('copy')) {
                    setTimeout(copy_sources, 500);
                } else {
                    console.log('Sources copied!');
                }
            }
           
            copy_sources();
        }
    }
   
    get_sources();
} else {
    console.log('There is no Adaptive package in this content.');
}
```

Line 45 is what isn't working.

That code won't make a lot of sense, but here's the use case:

I'm trying to automate part of my job by injecting some JavaScript into the Chrome DevTools console on our CMS that we use for video content where I work.  What the script does is click a few elements, then grabs some file locations and copies them to the clipboard as comma separated values.  I had this working just fine before, but I decided to try and make the script better...and now the `document.execCommand('copy')` is just not working.

As you can see, I use some recursion to continuously select the `hidden` input value and then I try to copy it, and if it fails, I try again in 500 ms.  I also log `'running'` to ensure the function is actually running (it is).  The `execCommand()` function keeps returning false every 500ms.  BUT, if I type it into the console manually and run it, it returns true and works fine even as the recursive function continues to return false.  So for some reason, it won't work in the context of my script, but works totally fine when run manually.

Like I said before, it WAS working programatically before, but I changed some stuff to make the script better and more automated, and it won't work anymore.  Here's the code with `execCommand()` working fine:

```js
const sources = [];
 
const stacks = document.querySelectorAll('span[data-bind="text:duration"]');
 
for (let i = 0; i < stacks.length; i++) {
    stacks[i].click();
           
    let renditions = document.querySelectorAll('span[class="blockUnSelected"]');
    renditions[(i+1) * 8 - 1].click();
 
    sources.push(document.querySelectorAll('p[data-bind="text: $data.name"]')[0].textContent);
}
 
let copy = '';
 
for (let i = 0; i < sources.length; i++) {
    const change_brackets = sources[i].replace(/\/tveorigin\/vod\/ae\//, '');
    const no_pd1 = change_brackets.replace(/-pd1/g, '');
    copy += no_pd1 + ',';
}
 
const hidden = document.createElement('input');
hidden.value = copy;
document.querySelector('body').appendChild(hidden);
hidden.select();
document.execCommand('copy');
```

I just tested that code and it still works, and copies the text to the clipboard as intended.  The only notable different I see is that in the older code, I run `execCommand()` in the global context, whereas in the new script, it's in a function context.  Could this have something to do with it?

Comment: Instead of pastebin, use the `<>` snippet editor here and create a [mcve] - we generally do not want to eyeball debug your code when a real example with error messages in the console may tell something

Comment: I've added the snippets!  But seeing as this is a script I'm injecting into a non-public web app, it won't even run anywhere :/

Answer (score 2):

So the solution to this was odd.  `execCommand()` can only be triggered by a user event handler, so what I had to do was attach a `click` listener to the `window`, then invoke a `click` event on the `hidden` node.  Because that triggered a click handler, that made it work!